# Using definition of derivative to differentiate $f(x)= \sqrt{x}+1$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Using $$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$ how would I find the derivative of $f(x)= \sqrt{x}+1$

The answer is $$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$$ but I keep getting $$\frac{1}{2 + 2\sqrt{x}}$$

Comment: Can you show us your calculations, and maybe we can find where you went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sqrt{x+h}+1-(\sqrt{x}+1)}{h}$$
Let $f(x)=\sqrt x+1$

$$\begin{align}
f'(x)&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}{h}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{x+h-x}{h(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x})}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h}{h(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x})}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+0}+\sqrt x}\\
f'(x)&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: In the last string of equalities for $\;f'(x)\;$, your lines 4,5 are, I think, identical.