# Find the derivative of the function using the limit definition of derivative:

Tags: calculus

Find the derivative of the function using the limit definition of derivative to:

$f(x)=\sqrt x$

Comment: First of all, please use MathJax format in the future. Wrap things with dollar signs and use backslashes for things like square roots. Googling "Latex square root" or something along those lines will make it easy. $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$. Second, please tell us what you've tried and what you don't understand.

Comment: Pretty much the same way as in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1016125/using-definition-of-derivative-to-differentiate-fx-sqrtx1).

Comment: Or on [sosmath](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/diff/der01/der01a.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the trick you can use, where you are likely stuck. Multiply both numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}$:

$$\frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}{h} = \frac{(x+h)-x}{h(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x})}=\frac{h}{h(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x})}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}.$$